# Radio button list not working in bootstrap modal pop up

Tags: modal-dialog, radio-button, twitter-bootstrap-3, radiobuttonlist

I am designing a modal popup in bootstrap 3 which will have a dropdown and a radio button list for giving the user to select his language preference. But unfortunately the radio button list is not working, I mean when I select one radio button for the first time it gets selected but when I try to select the other one then after it does not let me select that or else to deselect the selected one.

Can any one help me out ?

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;</button>
              <h4 runat="server" id="hModalHeader" class="modal-title">Hello Welcome to the Canon Professional Print Portal.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSelectCompanyLocation" runat="server" Text="Select your company's location" for="ddlSelectCompanyLocation"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectCompanyLocation" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                      <asp:ListItem>Subject 1</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>Subject 2</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>Subject 3</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPreferedlanguage" runat="server" Text="Preferred language"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdLanguageList" runat="server">
                      <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Javascript I am opening the modal in page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

You use `<div class="form-group" data-toggle="buttons">`. Maybe you intend to show your radio fields as buttons?

If you intend to have buttons, please see: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons. You should wrap your radio's inside a `button-group` in stead of a `form-group`. Also a `label` tag with button classes will be required:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
</label>
```

In the other case the `data-toggle="buttons"` possible cause your troubles.